# where is git-svn's git-svn TAG?

Tags: git, git-svn, rebase

I am using git-svn in order to practice with git. I mean I am by no means a git expert. In the beginning I found git daunting but I am getting fascinated by git's design and power. I have a question I could not answer searching on internet, perhaps because it is difficult to search for.

After some days of development on a feature branch using git (after cloning with git-svn), I want to rebase the commits before I *git svn dcommit*. I do not want to flood the svn integration branch with dozens of small, meaningless commits. For that I know I can use *git rebase -i*.

This command needs to have a commit specified. I have read I can use a (tag?) called *git-svn*. Indeed, such a commit/tag exists, I can *git log git-svn..*, or *git rebase -i git-svn*.

So far so good, this works. Now, after this introduction, my question:

What is this *git-svn* reference? A tag? A commit? Command *git tag --list* shows nothing, and *git-svn* as a tag does not exist on the other git clones I have used to work.

Another question: After I *git svn dcommit*, will that reference be changed? Can it be changed manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `git-svn` is not a tag. It is a (special kind of) [remote-tracking branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_remote_tracking_branch) created by `git svn clone`.

**Background:**

When you clone an SVN repository using `git svn clone`, by default the whole repo will be cloned as one remote-tracking git branch (to convert SVN branches to git branches, you must use the the options `-T`, `-b`, `-s`; see section [Handling of SVN branches](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html#_handling_of_svn_branches) of the manpage). In that case, `git svn` will create that remote-tracking branch as **"refs/remotes/git-svn"**.

Now git allows you to abbreviate references to branches; so instead of writing `git log refs/heads/master`, you can write `git log master`. Similarly, "refs/remotes/git-svn" can be abbreviated as "git-svn". This is explained in the manpage [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).

So to answer your questions:

> What is this git-svn reference? A tag? A commit?

It is a remote-tracking branch. It is shown by `git branch -a`.

> Another question: After I git svn dcommit, will that reference be
>   changed?

Yes. The branch "git-svn" tracks the SVN repo you cloned, so it will be changed whenever you fetch new revisions from SVN; this includes calling `git svn dcommit` and `git svn fetch`.

> Can it be changed manually?

Yes, it can, just like any other git branch. However, in general this is pointless; it will only confuse `git svn` and mess up your repository. There are situations where it is necessary (for example to re-fetch SVN revisions that changed on the server), but that is a different question...

Comment: I see, so it's a *(special-type-of)* **branch**. That's what I could not figure out :)

Answer (score 0):

I use extensively git-svn for my projects and I can't find a reference named *git-svn*.
Which git version are you using?

From my own experience, git-svn creates a reference named *trunk* that points to the last commit retrieved form the svn server. When you perform a *git svn dcommit* or a *git svn rebase* the reference is updated to the commit representing the HEAD revision of svn repo.

In order to perform the dcommit you describe, you can:

```
git svn rebase (to update your current branch to the latest svn revision)
git rebase -i trunk (to rewrite local history before dcommit-ting)
git svn dcommit
```

After the last step the *trunk* reference will be updated to the svn revision just commited.

Comment: If there is a remote branch "git-svn", that means that the whole SVN repo was cloned as one branch (namely "git-svn"). In that case there will be no branch "trunk".

Comment: I am using git version 1.8.4.rc3, quite a recent one, but I don't think this is relevant. @sleske got the point. In my example I just cloned a branch, not the whole svn repo.